Problem initializing experimental spacy coref
Using the documentation here (https://spacy.io/api/coref) to try and work a coreference resolution problem. I run into problems immediately when trying to add the pipe:
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
coref = nlp.add_pipe("experimental_coref")

RegistryError: [E893] Could not find function 'spacy-experimental.Coref.v1' in function registry 'architectures'. If you're using a custom function, make sure the code is available. If the function is provided by a third-party package, e.g. spacy-transformers, make sure the package is installed in your environment.
...

my spacy version:
spaCy version    3.6.0
Location         C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\spacy
Platform         Windows-10-10.0.22631-SP0
Python version   3.10.12
Pipelines        en_core_web_lg (3.4.0), en_core_web_md (3.6.0), en_core_web_sm (3.6.0)

my experimental spacy version is 0.6.4
all the documentation on all the different pages just import and use the nlp.add_pipe("experimental_coref") with no problems, and I cannot figure out what my problem is.
